# Getting the full RSpec test name from within a before(:each) block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

RSpec allows you to get the current running test method name in a before(:each) block, by doing the following:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.before :each do |x|
    x.method_name # returns 'should be cool'
  end
end
```

This is for a test like:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe 'Hello world' do
  it 'should be cool' do
    # test code
  end 
end
```

Would it be possible to get the whole test name with what it's describing, (a.k.a. 'Hello World should be cool') in the before block?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In RSpec 2.0 you can use (I'm not sure if it is a best way but it works)

```
x.example.metadata[:example_group][:full_description]
```

As for RSpec 1.X I don't know. And that's probably what you are asking for...

Answer (score 12):

I found the answer. Turns out there used to be a method called full_description on x that would do exactly what I want, however it was deprecated. The following produces the string I want:

```
"#{x.class.description} #{x.description}"
```

[Reference](http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Example/ExampleMethods/full_description)

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/metadata/current-example <-- documents explaining the correct way to do it..

Answer (score 8):

With Rspec 3.3 it works like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :example do |x|
    Rails.logger.debug("=== running spec example #{x.metadata[:full_description].inspect}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

or you can use the methods directly:

```
x.example.description
x.example.file_path
```

etc.

Comment: try also:
    described_class

Comment: This works in RSpec 2.13 (except that it's `x.described_class` not `x.example.described_class` as I initially thought).

Answer (score 4):

With the latest rspec release as of (04/01/2014) this has changed to

```
example.metadata[:description]
```

Checkout https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core#metadata for more information

Answer (score 1):

on rspec 2.12.0 `"#{x.class.description} #{x.example.description}"` works

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file as well. I used this to track down issues with my poltergeist specs:

```
  config.before(:each, js: true) do |s|
    md = s.example.metadata
    x = md[:example_group]
    Rails.logger.debug "==>>> #{x[:file_path]}:#{x[:line_number]} #{md[:description_args]}"
  end
```

Note that this is the line number of the example group (not so useful), but the description of the current example, which should help you determine which one is running.

> ==>>> ./spec/features/editing_profiles_spec.rb:3 ["User Edits a Profile"]

Answer (score 0):

This works in rspec 3.5

```
example.metadata[:full_description]
```

Fuller example, of how to access it:

```
  subject(:example_description) do |example|
    example.metadata[:full_description]
  end
```