# Getting the RSpec example group name from within the before(:all) block

Tags: rspec

Basically the question is similar to this one: [Getting the full RSpec test name from within a before(:each) block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816322/getting-the-full-rspec-test-name-from-within-a-beforeeach-block)

I have code like this and it works:

```
config.before :each do |test|
    p test.example.metadata[:example_group][:full_description]
end
```

Now I also need to get the example group name from within `before :all`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
config.before :all do |test|
  p test.class.metadata[:example_group][:full_description]
end
```